# DataSource Methods not calling When subclassing QLPreviewController

Tags: ios5, ios6, qlpreviewcontroller

I am using `QLPreviewController` for displaying documents, to remove the share button i am subclassing `QLPreviewController` like below,

```
@interface QuickLookViewController : QLPreviewController{

}
```

And i am using the class as Below

```
QuickLookViewController *previewer = [[QuickLookViewController alloc] init];
// Set data source
[previewer setDataSource:self];
// Which item to preview
[previewer setCurrentPreviewItemIndex:indexPath.row];
// Push new viewcontroller, previewing the document
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:previewer animated:YES];
```

But the data source methods are not calling.

Can any one help me.

Comment: how did you remove share button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interface has to tell that it's implementing the callbacks

```
@interface QuickLookViewController : QLPreviewController
<QLPreviewControllerDataSource, QLPreviewControllerDelegate>
```

Add the protocal names inside arrow brackets after the class name